# Basement shower with Redgard & Kerdi drain

Tags: basement, shower, drain, kerdi

We're adding a shower to an existing basement bath rough-in. Space is tight and we are planning to use a combo of Redgard and a Kerdi shower drain to save money/space/time.  Trying to use only a single course of 4" brick as the kerb, and the shower is only 30" wide so dont need much slope. Is the pic below workable? With a Kerdi-drain would it be better to chisel into the concrete subfloor to recess the top of the drain closer to the existing concrete?  With the sandmix sloped bed what's the *minimum* thickness advised at the drain?  Basically not sure what all the detailing should be. Thanks for any and all suggestions!!

[image: basement shower with redgard and kerdi drain]